# Fillable PDF using Open Office for Image

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf, itext, openoffice.org

I want to create a fillable PDF using Open Office or something which is open source. With Open Office I created the fillable PDF and it works fine with Foxit Reader; we can also save it. Now the problem is I have an image in the PDF which should also be fillable, like the other fields. User should be able to put his/her image in the image box and save it.

Later I will be reading the PDF using iTextSharp to retrieve the field's values and save it in the database. Other than the image everything works fine. I tried to create the image box with Open Office but when I open it in the PDF reader I cannot change the picture and moreover how will I read the image using iTextSharp and display it on the picture box so that user can save all the data in the database in future?

I tried with this but its showing null value

```
string pdfTemplate = @"c:\Temp\PDF\Untitled 1.pdf";


            var reader = new PdfReader(pdfTemplate);
            var output = new MemoryStream();
            var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, output);
            //textBox2.Text = stamper.AcroFields.GetField("f1_09(0)");

            Bitmap bimg = new Bitmap(stamper.AcroFields.GetField("ImageControl"));
            System.Drawing.Image tempimg = bimg;

            pictureBox1.Image = tempimg;

            stamper.FormFlattening = true;
            stamper.Close();
            reader.Close();
```

Comment: Would you show what code you have presently to extract the image from the PDF?

Comment: @halfer: But first i have to insert the image. So i was asking how to insert the image box so user insert his/her image and save the PDF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to 'put an image into a fillable form'. The PDF specification only supports fillable *text*, not images...

Here is a list of the general types for interactive AcroForm elements which are available according to the PDF-1.7 ISO specification:

- *Button fields* represent interactive controls on the screen that the user can manipulate with the mouse. They include pushbuttons, check boxes, and radio buttons.
- *Text fields* are boxes or spaces in which the user can enter text from the keyboard.
- *Choice fields* contain several text items, at most one of which may be selected as the field value. They include scrollable list boxes and combo boxes.
- *Signature fields* represent digital signatures and optional data for authenticating the name of the signer and the document’s contents.

As you can see, there are no images in this list...